# Как выполнять скрипт только после получения оплаты?

Tags: платежи, платежные-терминалы

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать следующую задачу. Нужно выполнять скрипт только после того как пользователь произведет оплату. Что то типо того как работают интернет провайдеры, оплатил услугу, тебя подключили, в не зависимости от времени суток. Каким то образом все делается в автоматическом режиме и в течении минуты двух ты уже с интернетом)). Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей подскажите в каком направлении искать.

Comment: Платежные системы после оплаты переходят на заданную страницу вашего сайта. Получив этот запрос от платёжной системы, выполняйте свой скрипт.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь